# Designing my dashboard in HTML page with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am styling my HTML dashboard using Bootstrap 4. The image below the code is what I would like it look like.

In other words, I'd like the text to be as big as possible and with very little white space if possible and where doesn't look to jumbled together.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        #table1 tr td {
            font-size: 100px;
        }

        .widgetLabel {
            font-size: 100px;
        }

        .mainNumber {
            font-size: 800px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <table id="table1" class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr><td><div>widget 1</div><div>55</div></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><div>widget 2</div><div>55</div></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><div>widget 3</div><div>55</div></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="widgetLabel">Widget</div><div class="mainNumber">55</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Image:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps make a runnable snippet with a bootstrap CDN linked in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty close - I did not go find a rounded looking font however.

```css
.block-of-things {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.custom-big-font {
  line-height: 0.5em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

.custom-huge-number {
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 0.75em;
}

.table.table-bordered {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.widget-header {
  background-color: #6AA84F;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.widget-number {
  line-height: 0.9em!important;
  font-size: 1.5em!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td class="border border-secondary m-0 p-0">
            <div class="border border-secondary text-center text-white text-capitalize widget-header">widget a</div>
            <div class="h1 m-0 p-0 font-weight-bold text-center widget-number">55</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="m-0 p-0">
          <td class="border border-secondary m-0 p-0 w-25 container-fluid justify-content-center">
            <div class="border border-secondary text-center text-white text-capitalize widget-header">widget b</div>
            <div class="h1 m-0 p-0 font-weight-bold text-center widget-number">55</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="m-0 p-0">
          <td class="border border-secondary m-0 p-0 w-25 container-fluid justify-content-center">
            <div class="text-center text-white  text-capitalize widget-header">widget c</div>
            <div class="h1 m-0 p-0 font-weight-bold text-center widget-number">55</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="border border-secondary block-of-things m-0 p-2 col-8 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-start">
      <div class="text-center m-0 p-0 custom-big-font">Widget</div>
      <div class=" m-0 p-0 font-weight-bold text-center custom-huge-number">55</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you use bootstrap, do you have to do something special to make it work on mobile devices?

Comment: Bootstrap is generic BUT you may have to have some media queries for size.  SOME are in there already ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/ but you may need to adjust depending on size even more.  IF you are not yet too established move to v5+ for better layouts and some class changes

Comment: Would you answer above change if i said i could move to 5.1

Comment: I will see if I can  create a bootstrap 5 version but no time right this minute to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Bootstrap 5 version; overall, really not much differs.

Note I did a slight bit of adjustment to the very large 55 and the text above so the descender on the top item `g` drops into the 55.

```css
.block-of-things {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.custom-big-font {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

.custom-huge-number {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 0.75em;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.table.table-bordered {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.widget-header {
  background-color: #6AA84F;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.widget-number {
  line-height: 0.9em!important;
  font-size: 1.5em!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <table class="table table-bordered h-100">
        <tr>
          <td class="border border-secondary m-0 p-0">
            <div class="border border-secondary text-center text-white text-capitalize widget-header">widget a</div>
            <div class="h1 m-0 p-0 font-weight-bold text-center widget-number">55</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="m-0 p-0">
          <td class="border border-secondary m-0 p-0 w-25 container-fluid justify-content-center">
            <div class="border border-secondary text-center text-white text-capitalize widget-header">widget b</div>
            <div class="h1 m-0 p-0 font-weight-bold text-center widget-number">55</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="m-0 p-0">
          <td class="border border-secondary m-0 p-0 w-25 container-fluid justify-content-center">
            <div class="text-center text-white text-capitalize widget-header">widget c</div>
            <div class="h1 m-0 p-0 font-weight-bold text-center widget-number">55</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="border border-secondary block-of-things m-0 p-3 col-8 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <div class="text-center m-0 p-0 custom-big-font">Widget</div>
      <div class="p-0 font-weight-bold text-center custom-huge-number">55</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to resize the font size dynamically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        #table1 tr td {
            font-size: 80px; /* Decrease the font size */
            padding: 10px; /* Add padding for better spacing */
        }

        .widgetLabel {
            font-size: 80px; /* Decrease the font size */
            background-color: green; /* Add green background color */
            color: white; /* Set text color to white for visibility */
            padding: 10px; /* Add padding for better appearance */
            text-align: center; /* Center text horizontally */
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%; /* Center text vertically */
        }

        .mainNumber {
            font-size: 200px; /* Initial font size */
            max-height: 100%; /* Ensure it doesn't exceed parent height */
            overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow if necessary */
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center; /* Center main number both vertically and horizontally */
            margin: 0; /* Remove margin to reduce space */
        }

        .right-widget-label {
            height: auto; /* Reset height to auto for the right widget label */
            width: 100%;
        }

        /* Set container height to 100vh (viewport height) */
        .container-fluid {
            height: 100vh;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr; /* Define a grid with two columns */
        }

        /* Style the left column */
        .left-column {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: top;
            align-items: center;
            margin:10px;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        /* Style the right column */
        .right-column {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 1383px;
            margin:10px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="left-column">
            <table id="table1" class="table table-bordered">
                <tr><td><div class="widgetLabel">widget 1</div><div class="mainNumber">55</div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div class="widgetLabel">widget 2</div><div class="mainNumber">55</div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div class="widgetLabel">widget 3</div><div class="mainNumber">55</div></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="right-column  table-bordered">
            <div class="widgetLabel right-widget-label">Widget</div>
            <div class="mainNumber" id="mainNumber">55</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // JavaScript to dynamically adjust the font size of mainNumber
        window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
            var mainNumber = document.getElementById('mainNumber');
            var container = mainNumber.parentElement;
            var availableHeight = container.clientHeight;
            var fontSize = availableHeight * 0.9; // Adjust the factor as needed
            mainNumber.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
        });

        // Initial font size adjustment
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to use a lot of custom CSS rather than leverage bootstrap here